# cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(DSHOW)

Tags: python, opencv

I have been working on this error for a while but can't resolve it.
This is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('webcam', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this is the error it is giving me.

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (193) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(DSHOW): raised unknown C++ exception!
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VVA\Desktop\test.py", line 10, in 
    cv2.imshow('webcam', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: test whether frame was captured successfully or whether it is empty

Comment: It is not capturing the frame

Comment: so find out why your camera isn't working correctly with direct show. Can you open it with other applications, like VLC, GraphStudio, etc.?

Comment: @Micka Do not worry i fixed it my webcam index is 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use different index number

Answer (score 0):

On my macbook the reason this happens seem to be that the internal webcam is index number 1, whereas the index number 0 seems to be the "camtwist" webcam driver.

The answer "just use a different index number" is correct. However it's not very satisfying - if you want to write portable code, what is the way to determine the correct index number of the internal webcam of the device? Better do a loop through all devices?